# How to use same sketch on two different computers in two different directories

Tags: compile, build

I have the same sketch one that I use at my desk and in the lab, but they are in different directories on the different computers.  This means that I have to change the paths to the includes which I have to fixup every time I transfer back and fourth.  Is there a way to put in a #ifdef that I can set at the start of the build that would include correct path.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the different forms of the includes.  Also say what operating system is on the lab system and on the desk system.   What directories are you allowed to rename on each system?

Comment: To do this I usually use a github repository

Comment: Having two copies of the code will result in disaster at some point.  Create a shared folder on a server, or your desktop, and place all the code there and then point both machines at the share.

Answer (score 1):

Open `preferences.txt` in `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Arduino` and change the path of `sketchbook.path=C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\Arduino` to `sketchbook.path=YourDesiredPath`.